# Format a string which contains numbers

Tags: java, string, numbers, decimal

I have several strings which contain numberic values.

I'd like to format these strings so that the numeric values have 1 or 2 decimal places.

Eg. One string might contain the value - "345.98765"

I'd like to format/change this so that there should only be 2 decimal places "345.99".

Can this be done? I am not dealing with any double/float values, these numbers are pulled from XML files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn the Strings into numbers and then format them.

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(text);
String formatted = String.format("%.2f", d);
```

Comment: Dude, you beat me to the answer every time ;-)

Comment: I will take a break then, off to watch some TV. :D

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this answer before but for some reason thought it wasn't working =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class, or with [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

More precisely you could use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

- [See Examples](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html)